# scala spark: Foldleft slow to evaluate transformations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I've been noticing something, and wanted to get an explanation for it (or at least confirmation.)

My company has a common pattern where in order to do something to all of the columns of a `DataFrame`, we do

```
colList.foldleft(df)({case(df_, colName) => df_.withColumn...})
```

This works in general, but I've found some cases where it's very slow, if working on a `DataFrame` with a bunch of columns and a complex upstream. What's interesting is that it's slow even before an action is applied; a not-super-long sequence of transformations can take 4-14 minutes to evaluate.

If I re-write the same code to use 
`df.select(df.columns.map(c => ....))`, the same code takes ~2 seconds. Calling `.explain()` on either produces the same output.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: can you post the explain plan here to identify  which one is taking more steps/time ?

Comment: `withColumn` will generally result in more columns whereas `df.select(df.columns.map...` looks like it'll only result in the number of columns that existed already? Is `explain` producing exactly the same output?

Comment: @ELinda Sorry, should have specified - `withColumn()` is being used to over-write the column. It's passed the same name parameter. `explain` produces the same (very long and complex) plan for either, except for things like #s assigned to columns.

Comment: @user3190018 Sorry but I can't - it's a few pages long, and even the column names are company-internal stuff I probably shouldn't share. That said, both explain plans are the same.